# Reducing EMI Radiated & Conducted

Tags: voltage-regulator, emc, switching

I have a switching regulator that operates at switching frequency of 260Khz that steps down a 28vdc to 3.3Vdc. 
The switching regulator output will supply current as high as 1 amp for the initial 5 minutes on power up then it falls off to several mAs.
Can you suggest any addition or modification to the circuit to improve the radiated & conducted EMI at the input?
I have followed Ti's/national semicondutor layout to lessen EMI generation and improve the ripple at the input in the datasheet. Any other suggestions is appreciated. 
Little bit more about the circuit:
At the input I am using TVS diode to clamp down large voltage spikes. DS1 is for reverse polarity protection. The combination of( Q1,R0, DZ1) clamps down the voltage to around 30V for large input voltage spikes.
[image]
[image]

[image: I added a second cap Cbps right next to pin7 and probed Co positive lead, the resulting waveform is shown below Based on the ringing noise signal a 5.6ns period is equivalent to F=178Mhz]
[image]

0.1uF added

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that radiated and conducted EMI will be a problem with this circuit?  Are you worried about regulatory issued or about interference with other circuitry?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Sorry about the images, I think I got them fixed now. I couldn't find an option to upload, only links.

Comment: @JohnD yes, I am worried about regulation issue test specially the DO160.

Comment: I see. One thing you could do would be to add a small RC snubber on the switch node.  This would reduce ringing and slow the edges to reduce EMI at the expense of efficiency.  You could put placeholders for the R and C and experiment with the values once you have hardware.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with EMI testing to say much. Your use of "wagon wheels" for component pads is new to me. I've only encountered them for vias. But it would seem to me that the use of wagon wheels negates the benefit of the islands you have (ex. L1 to C1). Why not just connect it with a single fat trace to eliminate the possibility of mini high RF antennas? The unecessary sharp corners comes to mind.

For other professionals, are wagon wheels on pads common? In this case I don't see them doing much to improve solderability but maybe that's a MIL-SPEC I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @lm317 the wagon wheels also known as thermal relief connect are essential for solder-ability. Without thermal relief you will have cold-solder joints and if you're soldering by hand the pads will take much longer time to heat up, you might damage the component in the process.

Comment: @Rocky79 For some pads like the right one of C1 I agree with the need of thermal reliefs. But as I said between C1 and L1, I think you could just have a simple trace (4 times the width of one of your thermal reliefs) and use the rest of the space for more ground. The current island between C1 and L1 is so short that there can't be much voltage drop across it. Nor will it require much heat during solder. If you agree with that then why not clean it up incase it's an antenna source?

The same would apply from L1 to DS2/CB.

Comment: @lm317, I have researched this topic further and realized. 
1-There is no need for thermal relief pads beyond hand soldering as the reflow oven will put all traces at the same temperature. 
2-I will need to reduce the trace width and make a direct connection as you suggested. 122 mils trace width is more than enough for the current going through  inductor. Thank you!

Comment: @Rocky79 with the 120MHz spike resonance a low ESL 1000pF would have be ideal to add, also. although my comment is a tad late

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thank you for your comment. It may come useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a conducted emissions point of view there are a number of things you can do to improve your chances of being compliant to the DO160 conducted & radiated emissions requirements.

One thing worth noting, your TVS on the input are at 600V is this correct or just a placeholder?
These would normally be set such their rated voltage is about the maximum value you would see. For the 28V it can be upto 32V (transients could be as high as 80V).

The first thing you have to appreciate is your switching frequency of 260kHz is within the conducted band (150k --> 152MHz) so you immediatly have a concern.

Your next concern is the switching speed of the FET within the LM2675 (it is not mentioned).

The aim is to present an impedance back onto the 28V bus that these higher frequencies are going to prefer to travel via chassis.

ASSUMING that GND is the not chassis & that you have a chassis connection available and equally this isn't for an airfix aircraft in which there is a capacitance to deck limitation:

A 28V bus EMC filter will be required & ideally local filtering near the switching device

Single CM filter section (NOTE: XFMR symbol used as there wasn't a CM choke available)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzuPP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

CM and Diff stage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8zhaM.png)</sup>

Actual values will depend on your specific spectrum with respect to the DO160 conducted emissions curve.

The next issue is the switcher & how to mitigate the fast transients that will occur due to the switching edges of the actual powerSwitch.

You are going to want to present to the switcher some impedance on its rails such that the circulating current does not want to go via the supply

A selection of decoupling capacitors really close to the IC will be required. The use of FERRITES on the 28_int:0V_Int (post the EMC) will further aid blocking the higher frequencies due to the switching edges (note the 1Amp draw will be via these ferrites)

Radiated is a bit trickier and depending on whether you have a fully metal enclosure, chassis tied to earth, in which case they are of less concern

Comment: Hi JonRB, thank you very much.That was very helpful. If we are going with Cat T for conducted susceptibility, what's a good value to start with for the common mode filter? How about the ferrite beads?

Comment: CatT for conducted?  CatT is associated with location and is subject to salt-fog (is this for landing gear or spd/alt sensor;) ) As a place to start... 150uH for the CM is a good point but you need to take a crude spectrum measurement (higher some equip for the day for an idea) . The Diff chokes can be the ferrites feeding the switcher. The issue is your load is unknown and that can couple back on so you will need ferrites and caps on the output as well (remember impedance back onto the 28V line). Also remember the 80V surge on the 28V btw ( section 16.6.2.3 ) w.r.t. your prereg/Vclamp & TVS

Comment: Hi Jon, Cat S is more realistic however previous system have used CatT for whatever reason.
I have uploaded the switching scope waveform at the input terminal. I added a second cap Cbps right next to pin7 and probed Co positive lead, the resulting waveform is shown above.
Based on the ringing noise signal a 5.6ns period is equivalent to F=178Mhz. Do you think a 100pF will do the trick to eliminate the HF noise?

Comment: JonRB, I am not understanding your suggested connection on the input. You have the TVS connected from the negative terminal to chassis ground. Shouldn't be from the positive terminal to negative terminal? Can you please clarify.

Comment: @ 100pF... possibly yes.  ~ the TVS to chassis. The reason it is on the +ve and the -ve terminals is the -ve battery connection isn't tied to chassis and thus can experience strike potentials (positive and negative). You should have some information with respect to what strike characteristics (supply impedance, waveform types etc...) The main point was the original voltage shown wasn't appropriate

Comment: The reason for the 600v TVS is because this device will be classified under CAT A for voltage spike. which means the max voltage spike according to section 17 figure 17-1 is 600VDC.